# If statement with return in JML

Tags: java, annotations, if-statement, return-value, jml

i need to set up a postcondition which ensures to return null if size_ is 0. Based on

```
 if(size_ == 0)
  return null;
```

how can i do that in jml? any ideas? Following doesn't work:

```
//@ ensures size_ == null ==> \return true;
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
//@ ensures size_ == null ==> \result == true;
```

Example:

```
//@ ensures size_ == null ==> \result == true;
public boolean sizeUndefined() {
    if (size_ == null)
        return true;

    return size_.length() > 0;
}
```

You could also simply write it like this:

```
//@ ensures size_ == null ==> \result;
```

Here is [the documentation for `\result`](http://secure.ucd.ie/products/opensource/ESCJava2/ESCTools/docs/ESCJAVA-UsersManual.html):

> **3.2.14  `\result`**
>   Within a normal postcondition or a modification target of a non-void method, the special identifier \result is a specification expression whose type is the return type of the method.  It denotes the value returned by the method.  \result is allowed only within an ensures, also_ensures, modifies, or also_modifies pragma that modifies the declaration of a non-void method.

Comment: Thats what I am saying. It sounded to me like OP is trying to replace the `if-else` thingie, therefore I said that. I hope there is no confusion anymore.

Comment: Oh, I see. I doubt the OP believes he can replace code with "special comments" though.

Comment: The confusion came from the snippet presented by OP. If he/she has shown the method with JML comments, everything would have been fine.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: what type is `size_`, `Object` or `primitive(int)`?

Secondly, what the return type of the method? `Object` or `primitive(boolean)`?

You cannot compare a primitive type to `null`, or return `null` where a primitive type is supposed to be returned. If we assume `size_` is `int` and the return is `boolean` then the the post-condition would be

```
//@ ensures size_ == 0 ==> \result;
```